# Is one serie of constraints a subset of the other?

Tags: prolog, constraints, subset

I have two series of constraints S and S', they describe possibly infinitely large sets. Say for example `S`: `x <= 10 and y <= x` and `S'`: `x <= 20 and y <= 20`.
Now I want to know if `S` is a subset of `S'`?

I thought I could try to solve something like: `S' and not (S and S')`, if it couldn't find a solution S is a subset of S'.

How would I put this in prolog, is this a reliable solution?
I am using gprolog but I can switch to another implementation.

Comment: Are the less than or equal the only type of constraints, In general this is an undecidable problem...

Comment: There are some more types of constraints, like: ==, !=, <=, >=. Is this really undecidable, I hoped I could just solve it with a solver..

Comment: on a finite domain, will be decidable. You can use implication #==> and domain enumeration, but don't expect anything fast enough to be usable on practical tasks...

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to ensure that there is no solution to (in your notation)  `(not S') and S`?

Comment: Please also see [a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4089885/1613573) and the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment by @false is correct, as far as I can see: given two sets *S* and *S*': if *S* is a subset of *S*', then the intersection of the complement of *S*' and *S* should be the empty set (there are no elements outside of *S*' that are elements of *S*).

It seems that [constraint programming over finite domains](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd) should do the trick if you are dealing with integers. Using SWI-Prolog 7.3, and doing your example manually, I get:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- \+ ( X #=< 10, Y #=< X, #\ X #=< 20 #\/ #\ Y #=< 20 ).
true.
```

The second query should read:

```
\+ ( % succeed if no solutions
    X #=< 10, Y #=< X, % set S and...
    #\ X #=< 20 #\/ #\ Y #=< 20 % complement of set S' (De Morgan's Law)
).
```

I think that the complement of *S*' could have also been written as:

```
\# (X #=< 20 #/\ Y #=< 20)
```

If you want to have a more general solution you would have to figure out a way to find the complements of an arbitrary set of constraints. Note that you *can* use the Prolog conjunction (the comma) as a logical AND, but you cannot use the disjunction as an OR.

Comment: CLP(Q) is most called for in this situation. While SWI's CLP(fd) actually a CLP(Z) is exemplarily correct (like SICStus), it still makes a statements about certain integers. There might be solutions in Q that do not exist in Z.

Comment: @false Need more to understand your comment: do you mean that it is better to represent the X and Y as a rational, or is it something else that makes CLP(Q) the correct choice?

Comment: OP did not state what the variables are about ; so this suggests rather Q than Z. OTOH, in CLP(Q), you have to do the negation manually. So you have to manually translate `not X #> Y` to `X #=< Y` etc.

Comment: @false There are a bunch of details OP has not provided, indeed