# SWI Prolog vs. GNU Prolog - CLP(FD) issues under SWI

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, clpfd, gnu-prolog, clp

I wrote a quick predicate in Prolog trying out CLP(FD) and its ability to solve systems of equations.

```
problem(A, B) :-
    A-B #= 320,
    A #= 21*B.
```

When I call it in SWI, I get:

```
?- problem(A,B).
320+B#=A,
21*B#=A.
```

Whereas in GNU, I get the correct answer of:

```
| ?- problem(A,B).

A = 336
B = 16
```

What's going on here? Ideally I'd like to get the correct results in SWI as it's a much more robust environment.

Comment: in SWI, add a domain and call label: `?- problem(A,B), [A,B] ins 0..1000, label([A,B]).` Better to place such details in problem/2 definition though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089885/swi-prolog-and-constraints-library-clpfd look at this question and answer, it compares SWI and GNU prolog

Comment: @CapelliC: Placing labeling locally is definitely **not** a good idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a good observation.

At first glance, it will no doubt appear to be a *shortcoming of SWI* that it fails to propagate as strongly as GNU Prolog.

However, there are also other factors at play here.

## The core issue

To start, please try the following query in GNU Prolog:

```
| ?- X #= X.
```

Declaratively, the query can be read as: `X` is an *integer*. The reasons are:

- `(#=)/2` only holds for *integers*
- `X #= X` does not constrain the domain of the integer `X` in any way.

However, at least on my machine, GNU Prolog answers with:

```
X = _#0(0..268435455)
```

So, in fact, the *domain* of the integer `X` has become *finite* even though we have not restricted it in any way!

For comparison, we get for example in SICStus Prolog:

```
?- X #= X.
X in inf..sup.
```

This shows that the domain of the integer `X` has *not* been restricted in any way.

## Replicating the result with CLP(Z)

Let us level the playing field. We can simulate the above situation with SWI-Prolog by *artificially* restricting the variables' domains to, say, the *finite* interval 0..2<sup>64</sup>:

```
?- problem(A, B),
   Upper #= 2^64,
   [A,B] ins 0..Upper.
```

In response, we now get with SWI-Prolog:

```
A = 336,
B = 16,
Upper = 18446744073709551616.
```

So, restricting the domain to a *finite* subset of integers has allowed us to replicate the result we know from GNU Prolog also with the CLP(FD) solver of SWI-Prolog or its successor, [**CLP(Z)**](https://github.com/triska/clpz).

## The reason for this

The ambition of CLP(Z) is to completely **replace low-level arithmetic predicates** in user programs **by high-level declarative alternatives** that can be used as true relations and of course also as *drop-in* replacements. For this reason, CLP(Z) supports *unbounded* integers, which can grow as large as your computer's memory allows. In CLP(Z), the default domain of all integer variables is the set of *all* integers. This means that certain propagations that are applied for *bounded* domains are not performed as long as one of the domains is infinite.

For example:

```
?- X #> Y, Y #> X.
X#=<Y+ -1,
Y#=<X+ -1.
```

This is a *conditional* answer: The original query is satisfiable *iff* the so-called *residual constraints* are satisfiable.

In contrast, we get with finite domains:

```
?- X #> Y, Y #> X, [X,Y] ins -5000..2000.
false.
```

*As long as all domains are finite, we expect roughly the same propagation strength from the involved systems.*

## An inherent limitation

Solving equations over integers is [**undecidable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem) in general. So, for CLP(Z), we know that there is *no* decision algorithm that always yields correct results.

For this reason, you sometimes get *residual constraints* instead of an unconditional answer. Over *finite* sets of integers, equations are of course decidable: If all domains are finite and you do not get a concrete solution as answer, use one of the *enumeration predicates* to exhaustively search for solutions.

In systems that can reason over infinite sets of integers, you will sooner or later, and *necessarily*, encounter such phenomena.

Comment: Fast response for `Upper #= 7^7^5` — respect!

Comment: Wow, great answer. Thanks!